# What is the difference between $ \| g\|_{q}^{q}$ and $ \| g\|_{q}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

let $p$ and $q$ are two  exponents such that $p$ is the conjugate exponent  of $q$ ,  I can't get a difference between the two following notation  $ \| .\|_{q}^{q}$  and $ \| .\|_{q}$, for example in the solution of [this exercice ,Exercice 5](http://www.bibmath.net/ressources/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=bde/analyse/integration/espacesLp&type=fexo) , The Author used two following identities:

$$\|f\|_p^p=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|^{p+pq-2p}dx=\|g\|_q^q \tag{1}$$

$$T(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|^q=\|g\|_q^q \tag{2}$$

How $(1)$ and $(2)$ are same ? and What is the difference between $ \| g\|_{q}^{q}$  and $ \| g\|_{q}$  ?

Comment: The $q$ in the SUPER script position is really what it looks like: an exponent. For instance if $q=2$, and and $||g||_q = 3$, then $||g||_q^q = 9$.

Comment: $\|g\|_q^q = (\|g\|_q)^q$.

Comment: (The integrands in) Equations (1) and (2) are the same because, as you mentioned, $p$ and $q$ are the same—that is $p(q-1)=q$, or in its usual familiar form $1=\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}$.